Google Datastore/Firestore - generational timestamp
Is it scalable to index a daily timestamp on an entity that only increases in value once per day? In essence, similar to a generation field as explained in the best practice docs here (although that doc link focuses on deletes, I am focused on writes). The field would have a value of 1 on day one, 2 the next day, and so on. Then you could sort on that generation field to get entities sorted by day.
Are there any hotspot issues for such a model? Because technically it is a monotonically increasing field, but the value only increases once per day.
EDITS:
Consider an entity that looks like this:
Task
 tag: String
 generation: Integer

Elsewhere in the application is a static global Integer set to a value of 1.
static int GLOBAL_VARIABLE = 1;
The value of this global counter increases by 1 every day at a specific time, perhaps by deploying a new application with the hardcoded value updated.
When writing a Task entity, the generation field gets set to that global integer.
Now you can query for all Task entities with a given tag and generation. You could also sort by generation, giving you Tasks that are from today at the top of the list and subsequent days towards the bottom of the list.
Would something like this be scalable? Or does this run into problems? Let's assume you are writing very frequently, more than 500 times per second.

The section of docs that you linked specifically refers to the issue of bulk deletion of documents whose fields are indexed in a narrow range causing slow queries until compaction completes.  Is that your concern here?  Because if deletion and slow queries aren't part of your problem statement, I'd say that the linked documentation doesn't have anything specific to say about it.

@DougStevenson I am focused on writes, not deletes. I linked that document because it mentions a strategy I haven't seen else where with the concept of generations to help with monotonically increasing fields.

I'm not really clear on how your proposed scheme works in practice, and how exactly it intends to avoid the documented limits on monotonic indexed field writes.

@DougStevenson I added an example of how the schema works. Please let me know if I need to clarify further.

Indexing monotonically changing values doesn't scale and can lead to hotspots, even if it only updates once a day. If the generation field is used for frequent querying and sorting, it can still cause performance issues. Also check this  link1 & link2

I don't see how the fact that the generation field changing once per day has any bearing on the documented limits of indexes.  Hotspotting is only a problem when documents in a collection are frequently written in a narrow range. The problem statement doesn't say anything about the about the rate of writes, so it's impossible to say if there will be a problem. I suggest simulating your expected load, and benchmark the results to see if there is a problem.

@SathiAiswarya Why would the generation field cause performance issues for querying and sorting once the entities are already written? I thought that hotspotting only occurs when writing monotonically increasing data, not when reading it. Doug also commented above that "Hotspotting is only a problem when documents in a collection are frequently written in a narrow range."

@DougStevenson I updated my question to say that let's assume writes are happening more than 500 times per second. So, on Monday, the value of generation is 1 and is written more than 500 times per second. On Tuesday, the value of generation is 2 and is written more than 500 times per second. And so on.. Will this cause performance issues when writing data? Will this cause performance issues when executing queries?

So you're saying you have a generation field instead of a timestamp?   If that's the case, it's not really a timestamp at all, and it's also not at all monotonically increasing for the unit of time where performance is an issue.

@DougStevenson Exactly. I do not index an actual timestamp, only the generation. However, that generation increases once per day. Technically it is monotonically increasing because it increases every day by 1.

The understanding for these values is that they increase steadily over the period of time of the burst of writes.  What you're describing is not the case. Writing the same value during the burst would not cause an index partition range to have to grow at all.

@DougStevenson That makes sense then. Thanks for your help!

@Micro I have posted comment as a community wiki. so that others could spot the workaround easier

Answering this as a community wiki. As Doug Stevenson mentioned in comments

you have a generation field not a  timestamp  where performance is an issue
In your scenario you have the generation field increasing once per day and is written more than 500 times per second, all the records for the given day have the same generation  value. So Writing the same value during the burst would not cause an index partition range to have to grow at all.

